# Как очистить предыдущий экран из стека навигации в React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Как очистить предыдущий экран из стека навигации в React Native?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0, // <-- currect active route from actions array
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'myRouteWithDisabledBackFunctionality' }),
  ],
});

this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42831685/disable-back-button-in-react-navigation